# Why does “$temp = 0; echo ~$temp;” print -1?

Tags: php

Can anybody tell the internal procedure of the below code

```
<? $temp = 0; echo ~$temp; ?> 
   //instead of 1 it displays -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise-not (~):

This inverts each bit of its operand. If the operand is a floating point value, it is truncated to an integer prior to the calculation. If the operand is between 0 and 4294967295 (0xffffffff), it will be treated as an unsigned 32-bit value. Otherwise, it is treated as a signed 64-bit value

Its because you're actually dealing with a full 32-bit unsigned integer with NOT. What that means is you're not simply inverting 0001 but inverting 00000000000000000000000000000001

which becomes  11111111111111111111111111111110

essentially this is the number + 1 and negated. so 1 becomes -(num+1) which is -1 or
1111111111111111111111111111110
in binary (unsigned)

for example:-
$temp=1; echo~$temp; print -2 //-(n++)

Answer (score 4):

```
echo ~$temp;
     ^bitwise not operator
```

Assuming 32-bit, **[Bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)** inverse of `0000` is `FFFF` (All `1`'s) which is `-1`, in signed int's case.

---

**Another way to look at it**: What `~` did is to give you the  **[(One's complement)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement)**

In order to get the negative of a number, you take the 2's complement, which is just the 
`1's complement + 1`

So,

```
(1's complement of 0) + 1 = 0 //negative 0 is 0
hence, 1's complement of 0 = -1
```

Comment: Nice answer coming from Cthulhu.

Comment: the sign is quite important;)

Answer (score 0):

Because `~0` is `-1`.

`~` operator reverts every bit of `0`.

The relation is: `-$temp === ~$temp + 1`